# servlet-listener and MIME type support for equinox

Tags: servlets, osgi, equinox, osgi-bundle, embedded-osgi

I have embedded equinox framework in tomcat 7.x using bridge.war and steps given at

http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/server/http_in_container.php

I have developed an osgi bundle which contains servlet registration code and as expected this servlet runs over the bridge.

My goal is to support servlet apis and web.xml functionality in this osgi bundle so that I can port an existing web application in osgi.

For now,I am using "**org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.ExtendedHttpService**" to register servlet filters and servlets.

However,ExtendedHttpService does not have a method to register a servlet-listener.

Can anyone suggest me how can I support/register servlet listeners and MIME types in an osgi bundle which contains my servlet registration code.